# Investor Badge: Good form/Bad form on editing question?

Tags: discussion, badges, bounties

I've just opened a bounty on another person's question: [php and true type collection in gd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569684/php-and-true-type-collection-in-gd). I have the identical question with one notable difference - I would like the programming language/platform to be different. The OP is asking for PHP and I need .NET or GDI. I didn't think it worthwhile to open a whole new question on this as it would be considered a dupe (even the font he's trying to break apart is the same one I'm dealing with).

So I just edited the question to add a note from myself. My question is: how much farther could/should I take the edits? Changing tags to [.net] and [gdi+] (I've added the last one)? Rejigger the question entirely to suit my bounty (i.e. remove all non-.NET references)? Or just leave as is?

The question is more about etiquette and what norms should be applied when opening a bounty on another person's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to ask a different question.

Imho you should have posted a new one, the bounty is not meant to change the original question just give it more attention.

Comment: Nah, I don't. In fact, if someone could post the code in PHP, I'd be fine with that as it's likely to lead me a way to do it in .NET - it's just that the preference is .NET.

Comment: If that is the case I would possibly leave a comment to that affect, but I would avoid editing the question body and changing the authors intention